# Conditionally select some parts of table

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to conditionally select some columns of my table.
The structure of my table could look weird, but I have no influence on that:

```
| id |    col1|1    |    col2|1    |    col1|2    |    col2|2    |    col1|3    |    col2|3    |
|:--:|:------------:|:------------:|:------------:|:------------:|:------------:|:------------:|
| 1  | some         | meaningless  | text         | don't        | mind         | me           |
| 2  | abc          | def          | NULL         | NULL         | my           | text         |
| 3  | dummytext... | dummytext... | dummytext... | dummytext... | dummytext... | dummytext... |
```

This table is divided into 3 parts, marked with a `|X` at the end.

1. `col1|1` and `col2|1`
2. `col1|2` and `col2|2`
3. `col1|3` and `col2|3`

I only want each part, if `col2` of that part `IS NOT NULL`.

---

This is my **approach**:

```
SELECT t1.`col1|1`, t1.`col2|1`, t2.`col1|2`, t2.`col2|2`, t3.`col1|3`, t3.`col2|3`
FROM tab1 t1
LEFT JOIN tab1 t2 On t1.`id` = t2.`id`
LEFT JOIN tab1 t3 on t1.`id` = t3.`id`
WHERE
t1.`col2|1` IS NOT NULL
AND t2.`col2|2` IS NOT NULL # this column is NULL, so I don't want it (including table t2)
AND t3.`col2|3` IS NOT NULL
AND t1.`id` = 2
AND t2.`id` = 2
AND t3.`id` = 2
```

If works only if all `col2` are `NOT NULL`, but if 1 of them `IS NULL`, the whole result is empty.

If you replace the both `NULL`-values in my example table, you would get all 6 columns, which would be right, as no part would be `NULL` in this case.

---

In my example, I want that output:

```
| col1|1 | col2|1 | col1|3 | col2|3 |
|:------:|:------:|:------:|:------:|
| abc    | def    | my     | text   |
```

[Here is a fiddle](http://rextester.com/RUCMP70464).

Comment: Why do you dp LEFT JOIN and then make sure no NULL's for the right side tables? Seems like you want INNER JOIN instead.

Comment: Could you post the desired output for the entire example input set? It looks like you're asking for a dynamic number of columns

Comment: A `SELECT` query specifies a fixed set of columns and their names.  If you want an indeterminate number of columns in the result set, you need to use dynamic SQL.

Comment: @Shruti: What do you mean by the entire example input set? Yes, I need a dynamic number of columns, depending on `col2|X`.

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code:

```
SELECT t1.`col1|1`, t1.`col2|1`, t2.`col1|2`, t2.`col2|2`, t3.`col1|3`, t3.`col2|3`
FROM
tab1 t
LEFT JOIN tab1 t1 On t.`id` = t1.`id` AND t1.`col2|1` IS NOT NULL
LEFT JOIN tab1 t2 On t.`id` = t2.`id` AND t2.`col2|2` IS NOT NULL
LEFT JOIN tab1 t3 on t.`id` = t3.`id` AND t3.`col2|3` IS NOT NULL
WHERE
t.`id` = 2
```

It realizes the described logic, but doesn't exclude the NULL columns, the result of the query:

```
+----+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|    | col1|1 | col2|1 | col1|2 | col2|2 | col1|3 | col2|3 |
+----+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|  1 | abc    | def    | NULL   | NULL   | my     | text   |
+----+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

Comment: How is it different from a simple: `SELECT * FROM tab1 WHERE id = 2`?

Comment: It returns NULL to col1 if col2 is NULL. Do you have only six columns in your actual table?

Comment: No, but I need so select them all.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, a query can not generate the dynamic number of columns in its result. So it's not possible to conditionally select some columns of a table. The result of your query will always return six columns.
But you could try to select all 3 parts of the table. For each part, if col2 of that part is NULL then col1 of that part will be NULL also.

```
SELECT IF(`col2|1` IS NULL, NULL, `col1|1`) AS `col1|1`, `col2|1`, 
       IF(`col2|2` IS NULL, NULL, `col1|2`) AS `col1|2`, `col2|2`,
       IF(`col2|3` IS NULL, NULL, `col1|3`) AS `col1|3`, `col2|3`
FROM tab1
WHERE `id` = 2
```

Comment: How is it different from a simple: `SELECT * FROM tab1 WHERE id = 2`?

Comment: You could see the difference at this link http://rextester.com/GBDM97429